# One More Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

While working on some variations of a physics problem (how does the normal force vary in a circular loop with a constant attrition coefficient with regards to the angle )   , I arrived at the following equation for it :

$f(x) = a(\int_0^x f(x) dx) + b (3 cos(x) - 2) + c$

(Where $a = 2\frac{μ_k}{R}$, $b=mg$, and $c=\frac{v_i^2}{R}m$)

I am not familiar with ODEs, so I don't know how to solve this for f(x).  What do you recomend as a method to approach these types of equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more puristic, write $$f(x) = a\int_0^x f(t) dt + b (3 \cos(x) - 2) + c$$ Differentiate both sides using the fundamental theorem of calculus; this gives
$$f'(x)=a f(x)-3b \sin(x)$$
Now, for the homogeneous part
$$f'(x)=a f(x) \implies f(x)=C(x) e^{ax}$$ Now, variation of parameters leads to
$$C'(x)=-3b \sin(x)e^{-ax}$$ which does not seem to be very difficult.